# Why the convexity condition on the definition of a face of a convex set?

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

A face of a closed convex set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be a set  $F\subseteq X$ such that:

1. $F$ is convex.
2. Every line segment from $X$ whose interior meets $F$ is contained in $F$.

Is condition 1 needed? Is there an example where condition 2 is satisfied but condition 1 is not? Thank you.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Condition 1 is needed. Take a closed tetrahedron $X$, and let $F$ be the union of two faces of $X$. Then Condition 2 is satisfied, but Condition 1 is not.

Comment: Or even take $F$ to be the two endpoints of an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TobiasFritz: Yes, $X=[a,b]$ and $F=\{a,b\}$ seems to be the simplest example satisfying Condition 2 but not Condition 1.

Comment: Of course, you're right. When looking for an example, I was looking for a non-convex subset of a face, and it did not come to me to look for a union of faces. Thanks!

Comment: @TomWerner: OK. If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!